# MySQL: Invalid Query. No error message

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing an appication on my WAMP now (PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17).

I have a function that displays all the events on the page. As there is a column called `city`, but in the database this column contains `cityID`, I wrote a function that will query the database to get city name by id.

So, that's what I have:

```
$city = self::getCity($row['id']);
```

and my getCity():

```
// Getting Config file data (DB connection info);
$conf = $this->getConf();
$mysqli = $this->dbConnect($conf);

    // Quering...
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = '" . $id . "';";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (!$result) {
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  die($message);
}

$row = $result->fetch_array();
$city = $row['city'];
return $city;
```

What I get here is: `Invalid query:` with no any error message. I assume my query is bad, but I tried to modify it in different ways (just to mention, I just tried this: `DROP TABLE cities`, cause there is just 3 or 4 entries).

But before I added the `die($message)` string, I was experiencing the `Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object` fatal error.

I must say that there is no any errors in `dbConnect()`, cause I call it from other functions and it works pretty well.

Where is my problem at? What am I doing wrong?

UPD: After switching the language of MySQL from French to English (it was set by default to French), and changing `mysql_error` to `mysqli_error` (my fault, sorry), it says me that `No database selected`.

Comment: it is not related to your question but mysqli dead. Use PDO

Comment: Mysqli is alive and well: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: where is the function definition?

Comment: @hakiko since when is `mysqli` dead?

Comment: why `mysql_error()` instead of `$mysqli->error`?

Comment: I know alive but meaning of "dead" is old for my comment

Comment: You are using mysql_error instead of mysqli_error. Might be a typo

Comment: Thank you, @hakiko, I will consider switching on this. But can you tell me, what is wrong with my query here? Even if the mysqli is dead (I am surprised to hear that though I was absent in PHP coding for the long time), it still works...

Comment: it should be `mysqli_error($conn_var);`

Comment: Sorry for that, my fault :) See the update: `No database selected`. But the previous function works great when not quering cities...

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: Your query is based on the WHERE clause. How/where is `$id` being defined? Shouldn't that be `WHERE id = '" . $city . "'`?

Comment: Negative. `$id` is a parameter inside the function, so I call getCity($city), but the the function is initiated like this: `public function getCity($id)`. Just... the different var names

Answer (score -1):

**TRY THIS**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities";
```

**Where you wrote this**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities;";
```

see the `;` inside the double quotes ??

Comment: Negative. It will work even with semicolon at the end. But I already tried both variants.